# Split string by hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I have  a strings in the format of feet'-inches" (i.e. `18'-6"`) and I want to split it so that the values of the feet and inches are separated.

I have tried:

```
re.split(r'\s|-', `18'-6`)
```

but it still returns `18'-6`.

Desired output: `[18,6]` or similar

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `my_str.split('-')`

Comment: [splits on my machine](http://ideone.com/VrmUVW). [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split normally replacing the `'`:

```
s="18'-6"

a, b = s.replace("'","").split("-")
print(a,b)
```

If you have both `"` and `'` one must be escaped so just split and slice up to the second last character:

```
s = "18'-6\""

a, b = s.split("-")
print(a[:-1], b[:-1])
18 6
```

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to remove the `"` at the end of the second string?

Comment: @mp2150, Just index each item in the list from `[:-1]`

Comment: @rmp2150,  what is the actual format of your string? I presumed you had an opening `"` otherwise your string is not valid.

Comment: I ended up using `s.replace("'",'').replace('"','').split("-"))` which is working well. Is there something wrong in the way I resolved it b/c it works fine.

Comment: you could just slice the ends off as in the second example but either way it won't make a great deal of difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[-\'"]')
test_str = u"18'-6\""
print filter(None,re.split(p, test_str))
```

Output:

```
[u'18', u'6']
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/hrX9nW)

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will do the trick:

```
In [13]: [int(i[:-1]) for i in re.split(r'\s|-', "18'-6\"")]
Out[13]: [18, 6]
```

This assumes that your string is of the format `feet(int)'-inches(int)"`, and you are trying to get the actual `int`s back, not just numbers in string format.

Answer (score -1):

The built-in split method can take an argument that will cause it to split at the specified point.

```
"18'-16\"".replace("'", "").replace("\"", "").split("-")
```

A one-liner. :)